# Getting BigQuery temporary table "destination table" using Python API

Tags: google-bigquery

My use case is to create a temp table and loading data from a select query, then extract the table as CSV in cloud storage using Python API.

I am able to create and load the temp table using Query Job however couldn't figure out the "destination table" from the job response which is required to export to cloud storage.

this is the code

```python
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    bq_key = settings.BASE_DIR + '/api_keys/storage_bq_admin.json'
    bq_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(bq_key, project='my-project-id')

    query = """
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      "CREATE TEMP TABLE segusers1 (user_id STRING, client_id STRING, inserted_at TIMESTAMP) AS SELECT user_id,client_id,inserted_at FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY inserted_at DESC ) AS top FROM `project-id.prod.users_partition_by_client` WHERE partition_id = 3666 AND client_id = '123456' AND inserted_at > '2020-09-17 00:59:11.461')"
            """
    query_job = bq_client.query(query, job_id="segment_temp_%s" % str(uuid.uuid4()))  # Make an API request.

    results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
    bq_job_id = query_job.job_id
    print(query_job.__dict__)
```

the query_job returns

```
{'_retry': <google.api_core.retry.Retry object at 0x7fdc41758748>, '_result': <google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob object at 0x7fdc3ca682e8>, '_exception': None, '_result_set': True, '_polling_thread': None, '_done_callbacks': [], '_properties': {'kind': 'bigquery#job', 'etag': '3uEKLSpG6pZPeLsnzA==', 'id': 'pid-107805:US.segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56', 'selfLink': 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/pid-107805/jobs/segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56?location=US', 'user_email': '', 'configuration': {'query': {'query': '\n            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE\n      "CREATE TEMP TABLE segusers1 (user_id STRING, client_id STRING, inserted_at TIMESTAMP) AS SELECT user_id,client_id,inserted_at FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY inserted_at DESC ) AS top FROM `pid.prod.users_partition_by_client` WHERE partition_id = 3666 AND client_id = \'cl3666dnx3klmb\' AND inserted_at > \'2020-09-17 00:59:11.461\')"\n            ', 'priority': 'INTERACTIVE', 'useLegacySql': False}, 'jobType': 'QUERY'}, 'jobReference': {'projectId': 'pid-107805', 'jobId': 'segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56', 'location': 'US'}, 'statistics': {'creationTime': 1600359344198.0, 'startTime': 1600359344308.0, 'endTime': 1600359346615.0, 'totalBytesProcessed': '1292600', 'query': {'totalBytesProcessed': '1292600', 'totalBytesBilled': '10485760', 'totalSlotMs': '6637', 'statementType': 'SCRIPT'}, 'totalSlotMs': '6637', 'numChildJobs': '1', 'scriptStatistics': {}}, 'status': {'state': 'DONE'}}, '_client': <google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client object at 0x7fdc42448588>, '_completion_lock': <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7fdc42355d00>, '_configuration': <google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig object at 0x7fdc423d8fd0>, '_query_results': <google.cloud.bigquery.query._QueryResults object at 0x7fdc42467da0>, '_done_timeout': None, '_transport_timeout': None}
```

from the document API explorer using the job id

```
{
  "kind": "bigquery#job",
  "etag": "3uEKLSpg961G6pZPeA==",
  "id": "pid-107805:US.segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56",
  "selfLink": "https://content-bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/pid-107805/jobs/segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56?location=US",
  "user_email": "storage-bq-admin@pid-107805.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "\n            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE\n      \"CREATE TEMP TABLE segusers1 (user_id STRING, client_id STRING, inserted_at TIMESTAMP) AS SELECT user_id,client_id,inserted_at FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY inserted_at DESC ) AS top FROM `pid-107805.prod.users_partition_by_client` WHERE partition_id = 3666 AND client_id = 'cl3666dnx3klmb' AND inserted_at \u003e '2020-09-17 00:59:11.461')\"\n            ",
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
      "useLegacySql": false
    },
    "jobType": "QUERY"
  },
  "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "pid-107805",
    "jobId": "segment_temp_3f7e533f-eb64-427f-bbb6-d3e31d78ca56",
    "location": "US"
  },
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1600359344198",
    "startTime": "1600359344308",
    "endTime": "1600359346615",
    "totalBytesProcessed": "1292600",
    "query": {
      "totalBytesProcessed": "1292600",
      "totalBytesBilled": "10485760",
      "totalSlotMs": "6637",
      "statementType": "SCRIPT"
    },
    "totalSlotMs": "6637",
    "numChildJobs": "1",
    "scriptStatistics": {}
  },
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  }
}
```

both returns without the required destinationTable details, i presume query should hold the  values of newly created table's datasetId. Not sure what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of a misuse of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and CREATE TEMP table in your code.

If you remove both, your query become a straight SELECT like:

```python
    query = """
            SELECT user_id,client_id,inserted_at ...
            """
```

Then you will be able find destination table in the job similar to:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "jobType": "QUERY", 
    "query": {
      "destinationTable": {     <======== what you're looking for
        "datasetId": "_c53c0a2640dc04748b94ebc5d7193a6976b85fa1", 
        "projectId": "yourProject", 
        "tableId": "anon8b75560af5d60d88fd40befe1371bb83696c86e1"
      }, 
...
```

Comment: This is creating normal table isn't? I'm trying to create temp table instead of regular table which requires scripting. Cost cutting is the main reason why i am going for temp table

Comment: Both this query results table and TEMP table in scripting are in a temporary dataset and have life span of 24 hours, they are not different at all.